# Marking a row as 'used' with UPDATE

Tags: mysql, sql

I want to see with a SQL `UPDATE` query, whether a id was already used. The response should also differentiate between an invalid id and an id that was already used.

My approach with an example:
Storing voters in a SQL database.
Call table `Voters` with columns `vote_id` (unique), `voted` (0 or 1), and `already_voted`(0 or 1):

- Voter `x` votes for the first time and has valid `vote_id`: check `voted`.
- `x` comes in a second time: reject by checking `already_voted`.
- `x` comes in a third time: `voted` and `already_voted` are both checked. No update. But I want 'no update' for the scenario when the `vote_id` is invalid.
- `y` has no valid `vote_id`: no update.

I don't understand why `voted` jumps back to 0 when `already_voted` is changed from 0 to 1:

```
UPDATE Voters        
SET     already_voted = CASE WHEN voted = 1 THEN 1 END,
        voted = CASE WHEN voted = 0 THEN 1 END
WHERE vote_id='12345'
```

I'm also open for a completely different approach. Thanks for your time.

Comment: Why not create another table with votes? This looks super messy.

Answer (score 0):

Try this :

```
UPDATE Voters        
SET     already_voted = CASE WHEN voted = 1 THEN 1 ELSE already_voted END,
        voted = CASE WHEN voted = 0 THEN 1 ELSE voted END
WHERE vote_id='12345
```

When voted is already 1 and you use your query , the default of the case expression is being used (for voted column), which is NULL if not specified otherwise.